# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when running flutter release mode

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, exception

My flutter app works fine in debug mode. But, when I run it with `flutter run --release` I am getting the following error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at e.c.M1.o.forTarget(Unknown Source:0)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at e.c.M1.p.a(:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at e.c.J0.b(:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.p0.V.e(:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.p0.r.call(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at c.d.a.b.l.O.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.q0.G.a(:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.q0.l.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: e.c.J1.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.lang.Enum.access$000(Enum.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:275)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:289)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2428)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.util.EnumSet.getUniverse(EnumSet.java:407)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf(EnumSet.java:109)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.util.EnumSet.of(EnumSet.java:235)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at e.c.M1.o.<clinit>(Unknown Source:100)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18551): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: e.c.J1.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime(18551):    ... 21 more
```

I've tried some ways like upgrading gradle, upgrading some dependencies to latest versions. But still it's not solved. Can you give any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**I am using flutter and , I  have found solution.**

There are some steps , you must do, please follow correctly:

***STEP 1:***

In */Android/app* folder:

find below files:
*proguard-android.txt*
*proguard-rules.pro*

**if they are not exists create them, with same name.**

***STEP 2:***

Paste this code into **both** files (*proguard-android.txt* and proguard-rules.pro):

```
   -keep class io.grpc.** {*;}
   -keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

***STEP 3:***

in */Android/app/build.gradle*
make sure that, theese lines have added:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release //If in debug, change release to debug

        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        shrinkResources true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' *//I add this line...*
    } }
```

***STEP 4:***

in terminal of Android Studio

```
flutter clean
```

then

```
flutter pub get
```

after theese steps it must work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

My app worked in *debug* mode and crashes in *build* mode. I check the log in my app and it said `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

The mistake I did was, I added the camera permission after the `<application> ... </application>` tags

I simply added the    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

before the `<application>` tag and it worked for me. Now the app isn't crashing

Comment: For me it is showing "internal error in firestore". I fixed it using "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50739346/java-lang-runtimeexception-internal-error-in-firestore-0-6-6-dev/70118366#:~:text=After-,spending,-several%20hours%2C%20I" this link. Anyhow thanks for ur reply :)