# Having the firebase issue when running my app in release mode

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Please look into this error log while running in release mode. i have to upload on the playstore and this problem gave me this issue.so basically i have added the
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();await Firebase.initializeApp(); to fix the issue but nothing works as it's the same issue again and again

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17180): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi
E/AndroidRuntime(17180): Process: com.casabazar.casa, PID: 17180
E/AndroidRuntime(17180): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.Q2.<init>(Unknown Source:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.<init>(SourceFile:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.G(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.initialize(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.t0.a(SourceFile:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.M0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.lang.Enum.access$000(Enum.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:275)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:289)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2428)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.util.EnumMap.getKeyUniverse(EnumMap.java:755)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at J1.c.<init>(Unknown Source:7)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at J1.c.<clinit>(Unknown Source:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        ... 9 more
E/AndroidRuntime(17180): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime(17180):        ... 19 more
D/FlutterLocationService(17180): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService(17180): Binding to location service.
E/AndroidRuntime(17408): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi
E/AndroidRuntime(17408): Process: com.casabazar.casa, PID: 17408
E/AndroidRuntime(17408): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.Q2.<init>(Unknown Source:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.<init>(SourceFile:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.G(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.initialize(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.t0.a(SourceFile:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.M0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.lang.Enum.access$000(Enum.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:275)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:289)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2428)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.util.EnumMap.getKeyUniverse(EnumMap.java:755)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at J1.c.<init>(Unknown Source:7)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at J1.c.<clinit>(Unknown Source:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        ... 9 more
E/AndroidRuntime(17408): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime(17408):        ... 19 more
E/AndroidRuntime(17457): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi
E/AndroidRuntime(17457): Process: com.casabazar.casa, PID: 17457
E/AndroidRuntime(17457): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.Q2.<init>(Unknown Source:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.<init>(SourceFile:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.G(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.initialize(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.t0.a(SourceFile:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.M0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.lang.Enum.access$000(Enum.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:275)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:289)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2428)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.util.EnumMap.getKeyUniverse(EnumMap.java:755)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at J1.c.<init>(Unknown Source:7)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at J1.c.<clinit>(Unknown Source:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        ... 9 more
E/AndroidRuntime(17457): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime(17457):        ... 19 more
```

**Edit 2**

Here is my main dart file where i just place the initialization of firebase

```
import 'package:casa/normalSplashScreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart'; 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  main()   async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
 
}
 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

// This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bottom NavBar Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
        hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home:  const NormalSplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit3**
I have received another error then before.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (37.9MB).
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
D/FlutterLocationService(18608): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService(18608): Binding to location service.
E/AndroidRuntime(18608): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi
E/AndroidRuntime(18608): Process: com.casabazar.casa, PID: 18608
E/AndroidRuntime(18608): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.Q2.<init>(Unknown Source:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.<init>(SourceFile:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.G(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.initialize(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.t0.a(SourceFile:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.M0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.lang.Enum.access$000(Enum.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:275)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:289)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2428)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.util.EnumMap.getKeyUniverse(EnumMap.java:755)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at J1.c.<init>(Unknown Source:7)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at J1.c.<clinit>(Unknown Source:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    ... 9 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18608): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime(18608):    ... 19 more
E/flutter (18608): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (18608): #0      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:165)
E/flutter (18608): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18608): #1      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:40)
E/flutter (18608): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18608): #2      main (package:casa/main.dart:39)
E/flutter (18608): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18608): 
E/AndroidRuntime(18990): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi
E/AndroidRuntime(18990): Process: com.casabazar.casa, PID: 18990
E/AndroidRuntime(18990): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.Q2.<init>(Unknown Source:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.<init>(SourceFile:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.G(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.initialize(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.t0.a(SourceFile:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.M0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.lang.Enum.access$000(Enum.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:275)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:289)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2428)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.util.EnumMap.getKeyUniverse(EnumMap.java:755)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at J1.c.<init>(Unknown Source:7)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at J1.c.<clinit>(Unknown Source:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    ... 9 more
E/AndroidRuntime(18990): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime(18990):    ... 19 more
E/AndroidRuntime(19040): FATAL EXCEPTION: ScionFrontendApi
E/AndroidRuntime(19040): Process: com.casabazar.casa, PID: 19040
E/AndroidRuntime(19040): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.Q2.<init>(Unknown Source:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.<init>(SourceFile:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.T1.G(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.AppMeasurementDynamiteService.initialize(SourceFile:2)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.t0.a(SourceFile:6)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.M0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:270)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.lang.Enum.access$000(Enum.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:277)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:275)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:289)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2428)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.util.EnumMap.getKeyUniverse(EnumMap.java:755)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.util.EnumMap.<init>(EnumMap.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at J1.c.<init>(Unknown Source:7)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at J1.c.<clinit>(Unknown Source:3)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    ... 9 more
E/AndroidRuntime(19040): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    at java.lang.Enum.enumValues(Enum.java:267)
E/AndroidRuntime(19040):    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Is it happening on both IOS and android? On what device brand & model are you getting the error?

Comment: So currently i am working on android and my device is Realme note 4 pro with android 11 installed .

Comment: Make sure your device has google play services if you are using a Firebase product that requires it https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services

Comment: Yes it have already

Comment: I think it going to be impossible to troubleshoot your code via the error log only. I am seeing this `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: J1.b.values []` over and over so that's where i'd start looking.

Comment: But have pasted all the error log while i was running in release mode. i have tried to remove the dependency which is related to firebase and it's working fine but when is was adding back again it causes the issue

Comment: I have edited my code please check

Comment: Finally i got the answer on another thread 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70522373/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-when-running-flutter-release-mode
by  @Söhrab Vahidli  thankyou so much finally it's over again thank you so much.